# Calculate driving distance

Tags: sql

Is it possible to calculate driving distance between two co-ordinates by using sql query.

I used

```
    geography::STPointFromText('POINT('+Longitude+'
 '+latitude+')', 4326).STDistance(geography::STPointFromText('POINT('+@Longitude+'
 '+@Latitude+')', 4326))/1609.34)
```

this, But it is giving me straight line distance between co-ordinates

Comment: Not really.  For driving distance, you need information about roads.  You can calculate the linear distances between two points, but that is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You will need to access web services that contain road information, for example: [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters).